# ctags error: "ctags: Unknown option: -p"

Tags: macos, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I've searched for this (exact) error, but I can't find any mention of it on the web.

Basically, I'm trying to install ctags (I've never used it before) on OSX Snow Leopard. Here's what I've done:

1. I downloaded the latest source package (version 5.8) from here: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/
2. Per the INSTALL instructions, I've run configure/make/make install. This installs a ctags binary to /usr/local/bin/.
3. If I cd into /usr/local/bin/ and run ./ctags (with no args), I get this: ctags: Unknown option: -p

Has any one seen this before? I'm obviously not supplying any arguments; if I do, I still get the same error (no matter what the arguments are).

Cheers,

-Lars

Comment: What do you get with `type ctags` or `which ctags`? How about `echo $CTAGS ; echo $ETAGS` ?

Comment: $ type ctags
ctags is /usr/bin/ctags

$ which ctags
/usr/bin/ctags  # This is the pre-installed version of ctags. I'm trying to use the new one I installed to /usr/local/bin (see step 3 above); it's not yet in my path.

The two env vars are not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check your ~/.ctags (or any other ctags configuration file listed in `ctags -V`).

You probably have something like `-python-kinds=-i` ; ctags interprets that as a single character (`-p`) option.

In any case, try to run ctags with `ctags --options=NONE` ; if it fixes the issue, it means that the problem comes from one of your conf files.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.. that turned out to be the issue. (I fixed it a while ago; forgot to update the thread.) Thanks!

Comment: Don't know how cheeky it is to ask, but is there any reason you did not accept the answer? Thanks