# Ctags error: "Unknown option -"

Tags: macos, atom-editor, ctags, exuberant-ctags

On OSX, with Exuberant Ctags via Homebrew, I'm getting a weird error when I run `ctags` inthe command line:

`ctags: Unknown option: -`

My `~/.ctags` file looks like:

```
-R --exclude=node_modules --exclude=resources --exclude=public --exclude=storage --exclude=.git --PHP-kinds=+cf-v --regex-PHP=/abstract\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/ --regex-PHP=/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/ --regex-PHP=/(public\s+|static\s+|abstract\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)function\s+\&?\s*([^ (]+)/\2/f/
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you on OSX? If yes, the shipping version of ctags doesn't support the -R option (and probably others). I would recommend re-installing ctags via homebrew (exhuberant ctags).

Comment: I do use OSX and it is Exuberant CTags is the variant I have

Comment: Are you sure your [~/.ctags file doesn't contain weird options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8745970/824425)?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the command-line you're using, but I ran into the same error trying to pipe a file list into exuberant ctags.  Note in the --help lists the `-L` option as accepting '-'.

So for my usage:

`find . -name "<my_file_pattern>" | ctags -L -`

MacOS: 10.13.2
Exuberant Ctags: 5.8